# Anaconda on Ubuntu - Error in permission to update using conda command

Tags: python, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

On my laptop on windows 8.1 I have vmware and ubuntu 16.4 installed.

I recently installed Anaconda 2.7 (x64) on it. The directory where anaconda is installed, is:

```
 /home/anaconda2/
```

When I tried to use the following command to update packages, I got errors as mentioned below:

```
 conda update --all
```

**Error**

```
 Error: Missing write permissions in: /home/anaconda2
```

I tried to use **sudo** and also tried by writing following permission under **visudo**

```
madhu ALL=(ALL:ALL)  ALL
```

**Nothing worked....**

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I think this can help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/726184/missing-write-permissions-in-home-user-anaconda2

Answer (score 11):

what about this....

```
 sudo chown -R <username> /home/anaconda2/
```

Comment: thank you so much, its working for me. "madhu" is username :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the command `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" conda`.

I faced the same issue when installing OpenCV for Anaconda using the command.

```
$ conda install opencv
```

This was fixed when I used the command below:

```
$ sudo env "PATH=$PATH" conda install opencv
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying it in windows, you can correct this error by giving permission rights to user. For that

1.Go to the Anaconda folder located in your OS Drive in Program Files
2.Then click properties
3.Under the security tab, click edit to change permissions
4.Under that select your user and give full control permission to that user.
5.Apply the settings and then reopen comand promt and type

```
        >conda install "package name(eg scipy)"
```

and that's it.
Now your package installs

Comment: What kind of Program Files? The question is about Ubuntu.